# Visual Basic Issue

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue with `StreamWriter/Reader` and using open files and closing files. Here is my code below.

```
Dim pathlocation As String = "file.txt"
Dim outputpath As New StreamWriter(pathlocation, True)
Dim inputpath As New StreamReader(pathlocation)

Dim contents As String = input.ReadLine()

contents = contents.ToUpper()
outputpath.Write(contents)
outputpath.Close()
inputpath.Close()
```

I am trying to read the contents from the `"file.txt"` and covert it to uppercase and append the result to `"file.txt"`.

Comment: You should say what error you are getting. Also, one problem I see right off the bat is that the file's path (C:\etc\etc\etc) is not fully qualified. This causes inconsistent behavior in that without specifying a directory, it will use the current working directory (whatever that may be). Also, you should read the file, close it, and then append the results. I'm hard pressed to think of a situation where you should use a reader and writer on the same file at the same time. Also, do you really mean append or do you mean replace?

Comment: I think the issue might also be that you're opening a `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` for the same file at once. Otherwise, seconded - you have to specify what error you get.

Comment: This title could describe 80,000 question here.  Please review this carefully: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using StreamReader and StreamWriter altogether by using the System.IO.File object instead:

```
    Dim fileText As String = File.ReadAllText(filePath)
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, fileText.ToUpper)
```

Comment: You do know that using File.AppendAllText uses the StreamWriter to write the output right? Its all from the System.IO namespace which it doesnt matter as essentially they are the same...

Comment: Yes I do know. Hence why you can use it and save a whole bunch of code lines.

Comment: Well yes, 2 code lines are better than 5 or six for the same task. In any case do you have anything constructive or even related to add here?